# Disposal and dishwasher are on different circuits but keep tripping

Tags: circuit-breaker, circuit

My house is about 5 years old and the dishwasher and disposal are on different circuits. Two weekS ago, I went to turn on the disposal and it would not turn on. I went to the breaker and the breaker for the disposal and the separate breaker for the dishwasher had both tripped. Turned them back on and everything ran fine. Since then, issue has repeated twice. At some point, when both items are off, the breakers for both trip and I have to go down and reset the breakers for both. Any idea why both are always tripping at the same time and why it is happening when neither appliance is running?

Comment: Are they tripping overcurrent? Or GFCI? Or AFCI?

Comment: Both circuits are GFCI

Comment: Is it the GFCI that trips? Or the main part of the breaker?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your initial question. The main part of the breaker keeps tripping

Comment: Get the wiring checked - as it hapoens when neither item is in use then something else is wrong. Have you put up a shelf recently? Drilled a hole?

Comment: Nothing of the sort. Haven’t done anything like that since we moved in 5 years ago

Comment: Any chance of rodent damage?  I had that happen and found a mouse infestation that had chewed through the cabling and caused a true short. But whatever is causing this, true shorts are DANGEROUS and can cause fires.   Fortunately,, at least for now, the breaker is doing its job.  Get this looked into ASAP.

Comment: Haven’t seen any of the typical signs of rodent activity in the house to date and did a full walk around and check just now and couldn’t find any signs. I live in a detached townhome and the electrical box is located directly underneath the kitchen (in the garage) so both circuits at play here don’t have much wiring as the distance is minimal. .

Comment: Electrician will be coming out next week. I was able to get the codes on the trips and for both it was 6 flashing lights pretty much every time, which indicates that the self test failed and the breaker needs replacing. However, one time, one of them flashed 5 times, indicating a ground fault. 

Couple of random questions. Is it just coincidence that two of these pretty much failed at the same time? seems odd. Also, what about the random ground fault code? Just want to learn about anyone else’s experience with these Eaton breakers. From what I’ve read, seems like they fail decently often